# Get value of <span> based on other <span> class within div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="calculator-section">
    <p>
        <span class="x"></span>
        <span class="amount">30</span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <span class="y"></span>
    </p>
</div>
```

What I want to do is get the number inside the `<span>` with class 'amount' within each `calculator-section` based on the span with class 'x'. There can be multiple divs with the class 'calculator-section' and multiple `<p>` within those with varying spans.

Roughly what I want to do (I'm aware this won't work, it's just to show what I'm trying to do):

```
var amount = 0;

$('.calculator-section p').each(function(i, obj) {
    if($(this).$('span').className == "x") {
        //Set 'amount' variable to value within <span> with class 'amount' within the same <p>.
    }
});
```

Hopefully this example makes sense. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$('.calculator-section p .x').text(function () {
    return $(this).next('.amount');
});
```

References:

- [`next()`](http://api.jQuery.com/next/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jQuery.com/text/).

Comment: I suggest this building on your answer as @user3420034 wants to set the variable `amount` to the value of the `span.amount`. This way he can store, in order, the value of all calculators.
`var amount = [];
$('.calculator-section p .x').each(function () {
    amount.push(Number($(this).next('.amount').text()))
});`
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rkd6u036/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var amount = 0;
$('.calculator-section p span').each(function(i, obj) {
    if($(this).attr('class') == "x") {
        amount = $(this).next('.amount').text();
        return false;
    }
});
alert(amount);
```